# Click Function sometime firing twice,thrice and much more

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I have use this click function for some event to call but when i am clicking the class it is sometime firing twice,thrice and much more .

Please give me proper suggestion for this code and how to correct it.

```
 $(".PositiveReaction").unbind("click").click(function () {
        var itemGraphId = this.id;
        itemGraphId = itemGraphId.replace("Like", "");
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: "/React/AddReact",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: { "itemGraphId": itemGraphId, "reactionTypeEnum": "POSITIVE" },
            success: function (data) {
                $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                    $("#CountLike" + item.GraphID).html(item.CountPositiveReactions);
                    $("#CountDisLike" + item.GraphID).html(item.CountNegativeReactions);
                });
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {}
        });
  });
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/

Comment: Just a suggestion, put your code inside a function (say function x(){}) and use onClick="x();" in the related html element.

Comment: @ManoNamo: Just a suggestion... *Never* use attribute based handlers (like `onclick=`) with jQuery, as you separate the code and handler for no good reason. :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Thank you for the suggestion's suggestion :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a delegated event attached to a non-changing ancestor. Then you do not need to turn it on and off (depending on your app logic of course):

```
 $(document).on("click", ".PositiveReaction", function () {
```

It will work for current and future matching elements.

A delegated event works by listening for events bubbling up to a non-changing ancestor. `document` is the default if there is nothing convenient/closer. It *then* applies the jQuery selector to the elements in the bubble chain. It *then* calls the function *for any matching element that caused the event*. This means the element does not have to match until event time, rather than when the event handler is created.

Note: Do not use `'body'` for delegated events, as styling can cause the body to have 0 height and events may not occur! Always use `document` as the fallback.

Should you actually need to turn a delegated handler off, use a namespace on the event name:

Turn on with:

```
 $(document).on("click.myapp", ".PositiveReaction", function () {
```

Turn off with:

```
 $(document).off("click.myapp");
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to rewrite the method in the following way

```
$(document).on("click",".PositiveReaction", function(){ ajaxFunction();})
$(document).off("click",".PositiveReaction",function(){ ajaxFunction();})

function ajaxFunction(){
 //Do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Note: if there are no parameters you can just use `ajaxFunction` by name without the wrapper anonymous function.